# apache friends xampp tomcat - how to add new directory to webapps folder

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I am new to tomcat and want to create a java webapp. I have downloaded and installed XAMPP Windows 1.8.0. There is a folder `C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\examples` and within it I have a file `test.jsp` and when I access it through the following URL it works.

`http://localhost/examples/test.jsp`

I have created another folder in the webapps directory "C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\myapplication" and within it is the same file test.jsp but when I access it through the following URL

`http://localhost/myapplication/test.jsp`

The error below occurs:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
```

Are there are configurations I have to make to add a new folder to tomcat?

Comment: did you find solution for this? Now I am in this stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost is host for apache web server, you need to enter this type of address:-

```
localhost:8080/examples/test.jsp
```

Apache runs on http://localhost/
and Tomcat runs in http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0):

I too had this same issue and at last found why it happend

I was running Xampp Apache and tomcat before. After that I stopped that services (thought so, but something is not good)

But it had an impact. That is the reason why it couldn't load these.

I just restarted the system. I can see the tomcat manager page and everything works fine. Its just simple.

Do a restart! And start only the tomcat service